# Redux filter array return new state

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, redux, filtering, react-redux

Hi i'm hoping this is a syntax thing... 
I have a search box, it passes it's value up to a reducer which i'd like to use to filter some data and return as a new state but with only the cities in the array that contain from the search value.

```
  case 'FILTER_LOCATIONS' :
    const data = action.serverData
      .filter(cityName => {
        return cityName.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.event) >= 0
      });
      console.log(data);

    return state;
```

data returns the filtered array but how do i update my state?

**update

Apologies, a bit of a noob.

serverData is on the root of tree and looks a bit like this:

```
serverData [{
  "id": 1,
  "full_name": "Eric Myers",
  "city": "Sydney",
  "lat": "-33.8678",
  "lng": "151.2073",
  "country": "Australia"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "full_name": "Ruth Torres",
  "city": "Simpang",
  "lat": "-7.1406",
  "lng": "107.0033",
  "country": "Indonesia"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "full_name": "Kevin Collins",
  "city": "Herrljunga",
  "lat": "58.0774",
  "lng": "13.0266",
  "country": "Sweden"
}]
```

Comment: Where does the resulting array go in your state? Please edit your question to include a brief description/example of your state tree.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us where in your state tree this data is supposed to go, but supposing you want to set a property named `filteredLocations`, you would do something like this:

```
case 'FILTER_LOCATIONS' :
  const data = action.serverData
    .filter(cityName => cityName.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.event) >= 0);

  return Object.assign({}, state, { filteredLocations: data });
```

If you're using Babel and have [object spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) ([stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/)) and [shorthand properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-shorthand-properties/) ([es2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/)) enabled in your presets, you can make this more concise:

```
case 'FILTER_LOCATIONS' :
  const filteredLocations = action.serverData
    .filter(cityName => cityName.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.event) >= 0);

  return { ...state, filteredLocations };
```

Comment: I was going about this the wrong way. Instead or trying to return an updated filtered function, i've moved the filtering to the component that needs it. Thus the original data stays in tact.